# How can I create a live clock with day of the week, month, day, year and time?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get to work a **live** clock using JavaScript where it shows the time/date in this format:

`Fri Oct 23 2020 13:27:10 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

I currently have this code where it shows the time `13:27:10 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` but I can't figure out how to show the day of the week, month, day, and year at the beginning.

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
  h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)";
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: why not `today.toString()`?

Comment: also you should use `m.toString().padStart(2, '0')` to pad a number with zeros

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Instance_methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target string format you provided is a result of the `toString()` method on a standard `Date` object.

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = today.toString();
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

startTime();
```

```html
<span id="txt"></span>
```

Comment: Also, do not forget to add the reference to the javascript file inside the html file and include the javascript function on the onload event. For instance: <body onload="startTime();">
    <span id="txt"></span>
    <script src="javascriptfile.js"></script>
  </body>

Comment: Thank you for you help!